# Right justifying with printf() with additional character

Tags: c, printf

In a table I am making, I have to print an integer representing cost right justified so that it takes up six characters in total which is okay, but I also need to insert a '$' character before the number. Is there a way to do this without making a new string that is just the integer with the $ in front of it?

Comment: Please show: a) examples of what you are trying to achieve; b) the code you've written so far; c) examples of what your code is doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This will print `[   $26]`. Brackets are there just to show the leading space.
`snprintf()` will return the number of characters needed to print the formatted string.
`%*c` will print a character after first getting an argument for the width.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ( ) {
    int cost = 26;

    printf ( "[%*c%d]\n", 6 - snprintf ( NULL, 0, "%d", cost), '$', cost);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing the normal printf call:

`printf("%d", cost);`

just add it in front?

`printf("$%d", cost);`

more help here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Comment: The problem comes when I try to right justify it though, if I tried to justify with that output, it would come out as "$     6", as opposed to the "     $6" that I am looking for.